# Grant local impersonation user permission to share

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2016, network-share

We have a domain connected server (Windows Server 2016) named STORAGE. The server has a local "impersonation" user created by our Autodesk software called AutodeskVault. This user is only a member of the "Users" group on STORAGE and nothing more.

[image: AutodeskVault User Properties]

I need to make a backup using the Autodesk software to a remotely mounted share \\192.168.2.50\SHARE but keep running into issues where STORAGE\AutodeskVault doesn't have permission to write to SHARE when the software attempts to create a backup. I am logged into the STORAGE server as DOMAIN\Administrator and am able to manually create, modify and delete items on SHARE.

Is it possible to make this local AutodeskVault user a member of a domain group (e.g., DOMAIN\UserGroup) which should have rights to write to the share? Or could I grant it some other local Windows group permission?

Just FYI our external Buffalo network volume utilizes account info from the Active Directory domain controller to set access restrictions for SMB shares using a web based configuration, but DOMAIN\Administrator already has permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either:

- create a local account with the same username and password and assign that account permissions to `\\192.168.2.50\SHARE`

or

- create a domain account with the same username and password and assign that account permissions to `\\192.168.2.50\SHARE`